# links on datatables 2 page onwards not working correctly

Tags: jsp, url, struts2, datatables, datatables-1.10

I am currently updating to a new version of datatables and the links on the first page work correctly but on the second page and onwards the links on these pages are altered.

I think my problem will have something to do with this https://datatables.net/examples/advanced_init/events_live.html

The data returned from the struts action is all correct. The link dispatches a jsp page into a div called `appSummary` under the table.

The code is;

HTML

```
<table id="listofAppsTable" class="table table-striped table-bordered">
   <thead>
         <tr class="userConModalHeader">
            <th>App Name</th>
            <th>Salsa ID</th>
            <th>App Status</th>
            <th>Critical</th>
            <th>Notifications</th>
            <th>App Level</th>
            <th>Score</th>
            <th>Target</th>
            <th>Stretch Target</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
        <s:iterator id="app" value="applicationModel.appList"
                            status="outerStat">

        <%-- Application Summary --%>
        <s:url action="applicationSummaryView.action" var="applicationSummaryViewUrl">
              <s:param name="applicationModel.appListIndex" value="%{#outerStat.index}" />
        </s:url>

        <s:iterator>
            <tr>
                <td><sx:a label="%{#app.application.cpaName} (Non-Scoring)" showLoadingText="false" href="%{applicationSummaryViewUrl}" validate="false" targets="appSummary" showErrorTransportText="false">
                <s:property value="#app.application.cpaName" /> (Non-Scoring)</sx:a></td>
                <td><s:property value="#app.application.salsaId" /></td>
                <td><s:property value="#app.statusName" /></td>
                <td>Y</td>
                <td><s:property value="notificationModel.getNotificationCountForUserAndApplication(#session.userid, #app.application.applicationId)"/></td>
                <td><s:property value="#app.appLevel" /></td>
                <td><s:property value="#app.percentScore" />%</td>
                <td><s:property value="#app.targetPercentScore" />%</td>
                <td><s:property value="#app.stretchTarget" />%</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
  <div id="appSummary"></div>
```

Struts.xml

```
<action name="applicationSummaryView" method="initApplicationSummary"
        class="com.bt.nfmi.action.lead.LeadHomeAction">
        <interceptor-ref name="loginStack" />
        <result type="dispatcher">/pages/includes/applicationSummary.jsp</result>
</action>
```

Jquery

```
 $(window).load(function() {
  $("#listofAppsTable").DataTable({
    dom : "<'row'<'col-md-3'l><'col-md-4'f><'col-md-3'><'col-md-2'B>>t<'row'<'col-md-6'i><'col-md-6'p>>",
    lengthMenu : [ [ 10, 25, 50, -1 ],
                    [ 10, 25, 50, "All" ] ],
    buttons : [ "copyFlash", "csvFlash" ]
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The links are made using `<s:url>` tag. But you should use the *action name* in the `action` attribute. The action name is defined in the `struts.xml` and it doesn't have an extension. Let the URL builder to build URLs. Using wrong action name in the `action` attribute leads to errors like that where the value for the URL remains the same and it's relative to the base path.

```jsp
<s:url action="applicationSummaryView" var="applicationSummaryViewUrl">
   <s:param name="applicationModel.appListIndex" value="%{#outerStat.index}" />
</s:url>
```

Comment: Hi  Roman, apologies, I had entered the wrong struts action. I have fixed it now. We have two similar actions which perform a similar actions for different users. The links are being created correctly when I have the datatables displaying all, however they become skewed when I user the pagination feature of data tables. Thanks for your help though :)

Comment: yes, it is skewed because `div` tag has wrong placement. Move div tag out of the table.

Comment: ah okay, I forgot to close off the table. I have closed the tag just now but still getting the issue. The div shows fine on the page one, but when I click one of the links on page two of the table.

Comment: the link on page one when i hover over it is " http://localhost:8080/test/LeadHome.action#  "      but on page two it shows as " http://localhost:8080/test/applicationsummary.action?applicationModel.applistindex=21  "

Comment: It could be if the data returned by the link has invalid html rendered to the div tag.

Comment: okay I'll go into the source and see that everything being rendered matches up

Comment: What is `sx` prefix? If it is a dojo tags, then you should move to jquery plugin, because dojo tags are deprecated. You are also missing `#` in the href attribute to reference value stack variable.

Comment: thanks so much Roman! I upgraded from dojo to jquery and it worked!